# Changing button style from .bordered to .borderedProminent when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to create a button that changes its appearance from .bordered to .borderedProminent to make some kind of illusion of a button that stays pressed when clicked.

```
Button {}
label: {Text("Xyz").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)}
      .controlSize(.regular)
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
      .buttonBorderShape(.automatic)
```

I tried using action function to do it but with no success. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your use case, You should create custom button style.

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        . background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.green : Color.yellow)
 }
}
```

& apply customButtonStyle to your button.
You can when button is pressed it will be green otherwise yellow. You can change this code to match requirement. Let me know if its useful.

Comment: It's very useful, thank you! One more question - is it possible for the button to change the color to a different one permanently? And when clicked again - the color is back to previous one

Comment: @Abrazjak It is possible. Use any state variable let say @ State private var pressed = false and instead of using configuration.isPressed, use self.pressed. Modify pressed either true/false on the button tap action.